# Paypal Express Checkout, confirmation required?

Tags: php, paypal, express-checkout

I'm wondering if payment "second" confirmation on my site is required by Paypal regulations or agreements.

I am talking about step/screen #4 on figure #2:

https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/images/developer/ECpageflow.gif
https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECGettingStarted

I want to do DoExpressCheckoutPayment just after user come back from Paypal to my site so I can print "thank you for purchase" page immediately without displaying another confirm page. I sell digital goods, without shiping and any other additional information, so this "second" confirmation is useless for me, but I can't find information if I can abandon this page.

Comment: Good question. We have similar payment flow on the one of our games. The solution might be querying PayPal in the background, I guess. If it doesn't break any agreement. Also, you might think of use of PayPal Adaptive Payment which is more user friendly.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, it's not required.
In fact, if you want to immediately call DoExpressCheckoutPayment, I would suggest appending &useraction=commit to the URL you redirect the buyer to as well. This will change the wording on the PayPal pages from 'Continue' to 'Pay now' in order to reduce confusion for the buyer.

Simply use https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-xxxxx&useraction=commit.

Comment: here is the official doc about useraction attribute - https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECCustomizing/

Comment: I cannot find an equivalent property in either the Payflow .net SDK or the merchant .net SDK